# Using macro in C11 anonymous struct definition

Tags: c, macros, struct, coding-style, c11

The typical C99 way to extending stuct is something like

```
struct Base {
    int x;
    /* ... */
};

struct Derived {
    struct Base base_part;
    int y;
    /* ... */
};
```

Then we may cast instance of `struct Derived *` to `struct Base *` and then access `x`.

I want to access base elements of `struct Derived * obj;` directly, for example obj->x and obj->y. C11 provide extended structs, but as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142163/c11-anonymous-structs-via-typedefs) we can use this feature only with anonymous definitions. Then how about to write

```
#define BASE_BODY { \
    int x; \
}

struct Base BASE_BODY;

struct Derived {
    struct BASE_BODY;
    int y;
};
```

Then I may access Base members same as it's part of Derived without any casts or intermediate members. I can cast Derived pointer to Base pointer if need do.

Is this acceptable? Are there any pitfalls?

Comment: As an alternative you might be consider using `typedef` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142163/c11-anonymous-structs-via-typedefs) answer) via `-fms-extensions` option in `gcc` or `clang`, but it's non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are pitfalls.

Consider:

```
#define BASE_BODY { \
    double a; \
    short b; \
}

struct Base BASE_BODY;

struct Derived {
    struct BASE_BODY;
    short c;
};
```

On some implementation it could be that `sizeof(Base) == sizeof(Derived)`, but:

```
struct Base {
    double a;
    // Padding here
    short b;
}

struct Derived {
    double a;
    short b;
    short c;
};
```

There is no guarantee that at the beginning of the struct memory layout is the same. Therefore you cannot pass this kind of `Derived *` to function expecting `Base *`, and expect it to work.

And even if padding would not mess up the layout, there is a still potential problem with trap presenstation:

If again `sizeof(Base) == sizeof(Derived)`, but `c` ends up to a area which is covered by the padding at the end of `Base`. Passing pointer of this struct to function which expects `Base*` and modifies it, might affect padding bits too (padding has unspecified value), thus possibly corrupting `c` and maybe even creating trap presentation.

Comment: It's true. I place different #pragma pack before struct definitions and horrible corrupt result of upcasting.